# Villages on "Old" Worlds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have the iPod 4th generation so I can't use "infinite" worlds. Are you still able to get villages on the "old" world? If you can, do you know any seeds that have villages on the "old" world?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find villages on old worlds, and any 'new' randomly generated terrain features as well.  This happens with any 'old' world that is updated to use the newest/a new Minecraft build that includes new features.

What will happen is, your old chunks that have already been loaded will remain as they are, but any new chunks, such as ones you find while exploring beyond the limits of your old world, have a chance of spawning any number of new things from the latest update.

Note that you won't find any of these things in the old chunks you've already explored - you need to explore new regions in order to find new features.  This doesn't affect mob spawning - new mobs can spawn anywhere in an old world.

Comment: Note, old worlds generated pre-0.9.0 will not expand to be infinite, and will **not** contain villages. What the OP means by "old" is the finite world size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a matter of fact I have an iPod 4th generation as well and I have came across many seeds for the old world type. Here are a couple
~ 1405715475 ~
~ 999 ~
~ Minecraft ~
~ wand ~
I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

A seed for a village is:   village is village

No caps just go straight then make a left turn
It has a blacksmith that has 2 iron and gold ingots and 2 ink sacks note: you will have to break into the blacksmith